# Big R project with several packages and developers: Best setup for easy version controll based on packages

Tags: r, git, package, integration, versioning

I have to restructure a big project written in R, which is later consisting several packages as well as developers. Everything is set up on a git server.

The question is: How do I manage frequent changes inside packages without having to build them every time and developers updating them after they made a new pull? Is there any best practice or automation for that? I don't want source() with unbuilt packages and R.files but would like to stick with a package like structure as much as possible. We will work in a Windows environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Does packrat fit your needs?

Comment: Do you practise continuous integration?

Comment: @Hugh Not yet, but I want to get them there. But I'm not that experienced in developing bigger R projects and doing continuous integration with it seems complicated.

Comment: Would something simple like `stopifnot(packageVersion("ggplot2") >= package_version("2.0.0"))` suffice?

Comment: @Bishops_Guest packrat is also very interessting and I'm allready thinking about introducing it

Comment: @Hugh would work to prevent them from working with old packages but still does not make the process faster. I looked into the options I have for build servers in R but yeah...nothing nice.

Comment: @Bishops_Guest I have the same question and I also thought about packrat. But what I understand, packrat is for dependency management. But I am more interested in version control of the code. Do you have experience there?

Comment: @Christoph maybe my answer posted could help you as well

Answer (score 0):

So I fiddled around a while, tried different setups and came up with an arrangement which fits my needs.

It basically consists two git repositories. The first on (let's call it base-repo) of them contains most scripts on which all later packages are based on. The second repo we will call the "package-repo". 
Most development work should be done on the base-repo. The base-repo is under CI control via a build server and unit tests.

The package-repo contains folders for each package we want to build and the base-repo as a git-submodule.

Each package can now be constructed via a very simple bash/shell script (“build script”):

- check out a commit/tag of the submodule base-repo on which the stable
  package build should be based on
- copy files which are necessary for the package into the specific package folder
- checks and builds the package
- script can also create a history file of package
- script can either be invoked manually or by a build server

This approach can also be combined with packrat. Additional code which is very package specific can now be also added to the package-repo and is under version control while independed from the base-repo

The approach could be further extended to trigger the build of packages from the package-repo based on pushes to the base-repo. Packages with a build script pointing to master as a commit will always be up to date and if under control of a build server it will ensure that changes to the base-repo will not break the package. Also it is possible to create several packages containing the same scripts from base-repo.

See also:  [git: symlink/reference to a file in an external repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844542/git-symlink-reference-to-a-file-in-an-external-repository)