# git link to a submodule file import problems

Tags: python, django, git, git-submodules

I added a file to my project which is a symlink to a file in another git project. I followed the steps in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770463/3573182 to add the other project as a submodule in my project.

Now the link I added to the file has some broken imports. 
Let's say my project A's structure is like this (including the structure of the submodule from project B):

Project A:
  - package1:
     -- link.py
  - submodule-of-project-B
    -- package1:
        --- linked_file.py
    -- package2
    -- package3

Now the 'linked_file.py' has some imports from 'package2' which is a package inside project B. 
But because project A doesn't have that package so the imports inside the link are broken and I cannot run project A. 
I know I can change the imports from `import package2` to `import submodule.package2`. 
But because this is a link, I think this will change the import line in the original file in project B which will make it broken there.

I used a link because in the future I need any update in the original file from its developers to be immediately reflected in my project.