# How to integrate two repositories_

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repository

I have two repo.(ex:repoA, repoB)
And, RepoA Branch master have update.json and more.
And I want to integrate only the update.json of the RepoA branch master into the RepoB branch master.
I would also like to update the RepoB changelog. (add update.json)
Tell me about it.
Thanks　you.

Comment: Looks like you might be looking for something like this: [git: symlink/reference to a file in an external repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844542/git-symlink-reference-to-a-file-in-an-external-repository/27770463#27770463)

Comment: Hi, does  rickvdbosch's suggestions meet your requirements?