# The mk files(envsetup.sh, build.sh) become absolute path causes build error

Tags: android, symlink, repo

I enforce a strange problem that I never met.  So I need help
I get the Android for MSM Project code from CodeAurora.
But all the mk files link to absolute path

Such as:

```
Android.bp -> /home/XXXXX/QCOM_PROJECT/build/soong/root.bp  
bootstrap.bash -> /home/XXXXX/QCOM_PROJECT/build/soong/bootstrap.bash*  
build.sh -> /home/XXXXX/QCOM_PROJECT/vendor/qcom/opensource/core-utils/build/build.sh* 
envsetup.sh -> /home/XXXXX/QCOM_PROJECT/build/make/envsetup.sh
```

[apps/LINUX/android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBHst.png)
[apps/LINUX/android/build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwllc.png)

But in normal case, it should be

```
Android.bp -> build/soong/root.bp*  
bootstrap.bash -> build/soong/bootstrap.bash*  
build.sh -> vendor/qcom/opensource/core-utils/build/build.sh*  
envsetup.sh -> make/envsetup.sh*
```

Can some experts help to tell me why?
Thanks so much

Server: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64)
repo version: V1.27

[repo init command]

```
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/platform/manifest.git -b release -m LA.AU.1.2.2.r1-03000-gen3meta.0.xml --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable --no-repo-verify
```

[repo sync command]

```
repo sync -f -c -j48 --no-tags
```

Comment: Could it be that the repo itself meanwhile has been updated to use absolute pathes in symlinks? See the comments to the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465436/git-how-to-handle-symlinks) question - maybe they apply to your case?

Comment: Thanks, but it seem not the root cause

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the root cause, just use Google repo and don't use CodeAurora repo.

It can fix this problem

Remove the "--repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable", it will use repo bin's REPO_URL to get the repo from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo